# Change ref of the parent from child component using Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I have a child component called `Navbar`. A logout is an option in the Navbar.

```
<a @click="(event) => {event.preventDefault();}">
  Logout 
</a>
```

I have imported this `Navbar` into my parent component called `Home`. And in the `Home` component, there is a div (a modal),

```
<div class="modal" v-if="modal">
```

And this modal will show only if the modal ref is `true`.

```
<script setup>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';
import {ref} from 'vue';

const modal = ref(false);

</scipt>
```

My question is how to make this modal `ref` value to `true` when we click the `logout` option in my `Navbar` child component.

Comment: NavBar component can emit an event `<a @click.prevent="emit('some-event')">` ... that the parent can handle :  `<nav-bar@some-event="... do things in here">`

Comment: Can you do more explanation in Navbar and Parent both? Thanks

Comment: no, because you have shown naff all of navbar and parent both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can emit from the child say
**Navbar.vue**

```
<a @click="buttonClick">
  Logout 
</a>
```

and

```
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['showModal'])

function buttonClick() {
  emit('showModal', true)
}
</script>
```

and then you would have used the Navbar.vue in parent like

```
<Navbar @showModal="setModalVisibility" />
.
.
.

<script setup>
function setModalVisibilty() {
  modal.value = true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Done Buddy :)...

Answer (score 5):

In the parent

```
<script setup>
    import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';
    import {ref} from 'vue';

    const modal = ref(false);

    const setModalTrue= () => this.modal.value = true;        
</script>
<template>
    ....
    <navbar @nav-event="setModalTrue">
    ....
    </navbar>
    ....
</template>
```

in navbar

```
<script setup>
    const emit = defineEmits(["nav-event"]);
    const sendNavEvent = () => emit("nav-event");
</script>
<template>
    ....
    <a @click.prevent="sendNavEvent">
    ....
    </a>
    ....
</template>
```

note `@click.prevent=....` - which does the `preventDefault` for you

Answer (score 2):

Try to emit an event from the `Navbar` component when you click on the logout link:

```html
<a @click.prevent="logout">
  Logout 
</a>
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const emit=defineEmits(['logout'])

const loggedIn=ref(true)

function logout(){
   emit('logout',!loggedIn.value)
}
</scipt>
```

in parent :

```html
<Navbar @logout="onLogout" />
<script setup>
import Navbar from './components/Navbar.vue';
import {ref} from 'vue';

const modal = ref(false);

function onLogout(logged){
   modal.value=logged
}
</scipt>
```